# How to add waiting time in lightning component controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I used setTimeout() of javascript, and my code to be executed is also is getting executed, but somehow the $A.util.removeClass and $A.util.addClass are not working and my component(i.e a Toast written in slds markup) to be hidden is not getting hidden. Is there any known workaround?

Controller method:

```
addDelay : function(component, event, helper){
    var delay=4000; //4 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Inside delay: ');
        var toastDiv= component.find('toastDiv');
        console.log('toastDiv:  '+ toastDiv);
        $A.util.removeClass(toastDiv, "slds-show");
        $A.util.addClass(toastDiv, "slds-hide");
    }, delay);
```

Here, toastDiv is the ID of div element of Toast component markup.

> Output of console: 
>   SecureComponent: markup://aura:html {289:0} {toastDiv}{ key: {"namespace":"c"}

which means it is fetching the div correctly.

> UPDATED CODE FOR REFERENCE:

```
        window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            if(component.isValid()){
                var toastDiv= component.find('toastDiv');
                $A.util.removeClass(toastDiv, "slds-show");
                $A.util.addClass(toastDiv, "slds-hide");
            }
            else{
                console.log('Component is Invalid');
            }
        }), 3000
    );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

setTimeout() as a "fix" for timing issues is rarely a good choice - just moves the indeterminacy to another place /or adds lag (4 seconds is an eternity). The correct way to handle this is with either data binding to myDiv's v.class attribute (best) or in a custom renderer.

Setting that aside it's also critical to note that myDiv is actually a component and not an element (Component.find() always works st the component api level). The remove/addClass() util methods are also operating at the component level (they manipulate the v.class attribute). Why does this matter? By introducing a callback using setTimeout() you have also introduced code execution outside of Lightning's visibility and any time this is fine you need to wrap your callback with a call to $A.getCallback() to allow Lightning to restore context and also run its event/render lifecycle. Without $A.getCallback() Lightning does not know to even look to see that you have change myDiv.v.class and therefor does not update the corresponding DOM element's classList.

See *Modifying Components Outside the Framework Lifecycle*
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm for more info - but like I said please reconsider your approach entirely and switch to a simpler declarative (value binding to an attribute on your component that contains myDiv) approach and let Lightning handle the timing etc.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I alost forgot about the getCallback() method...yes you are right it is out of lightning context. Also agree with your advise not to use etTimeout(). But at the same time , I am not able to fathom how can I make my toast stay on UI for some time and then go away...if I use data binding in myDiv as you said, it just disappears even before we can see. Can you please guide in detail how can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry - I missed the important detail about this being a toast/timed prompt - that is one of the few legitimate uses of setTimeout() :-)

Comment: I'm a definite newbie at all things HTML and CSS, but could CSS transitions be used to fade something out after a certain number of seconds?  I thought I remember reading that a transition also didn't have to be linear, and that it could have a defined ramp to it.  Maybe the first 3.9 seconds could be fully visible, and then it transitions/fades out for the last .1 second?